# Disable connecting USB as media device with Jelly Bean

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, usb-debugging

I got a new update on my Samsung Tablet and I recognized a change / problem.
I want to connect my Tablet to my PC without connecting as Media Device. I like to transfer Files from my Aclipse ( Java ) to the tablet. For that the MediaConnection should be disabled, I guess :-)

Any hints ?

Regards

Answer (score -1):

I have no XPs with JB but Google closed UMS (USB Mass Storage) support. My device with Android 4.2.2 suppors only MTP and PTP protocols and I can switch between them in the storage settings. Check this out.

Comment: pavian, that's not quite true: Google didn't close UMS support. It's the decision of manufacturers to further offer it or not. My shiny new tablets (JellyBean 4.1.1) still have it, and I know first-hand it will stay such. As a rule of thumb: If the device has no SD slot, it's likely to have UMS dropped in favor of MTP -- otherwise it's likely to offer both with 4.x.

Comment: @Izzy I agree and now I get it, it's because UMS is a block device protocol and this one needs exclusive access.

Comment: Exactly. With PTP/MTP, the storage presented to the computer does not become unavailable on the device itself, which is a big pro. The cons however are: MTP is not easily available to all OSes (especially on the Mac it needs some handwork), and low-level operations (which require block-access, such as e.g. data recovery software) can not be used this way.

Comment: I already tried to switch between MTP and PTP. But both do not allow me to use DDMS for Filetransfer.